# SVN Repository Authentication using SharpSVN

Tags: svn, authentication, sharpsvn

Can any one tell me how to authenticate users(SVN users) for a repository using SharpSVN Library.
That repository should only be committed by those users.
Thanks

Answer (score 48):

Use the Authenticate properties of `SVNClient`:

```cs
client.Authentication.Clear(); // Clear a previous authentication
client.Authentication.DefaultCredentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password");
```

Comment: This isn't working for me, is there some prerequisite for this?

Comment: Only the SharpSVN library. Are you sure of your user name and password?

Answer (score 14):

```cs
client.Authentication.ForceCredentials("user", "password");
```

For those of you who don't want to blow away your default credentials (if you're running TortoiseSVN on the same machine).

Comment: With this I can authenticate but it change my default credentials on TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 10):

You can also override SSL certificate errors by adding an event handler to `SslServerTrustHandlers` like this:

```cs
SVN_Conn.Authentication.SslServerTrustHandlers += new EventHandler<SharpSvn.Security.SvnSslServerTrustEventArgs>(SVN_SSL_Override);

static void SVN_SSL_Override(object sender, SharpSvn.Security.SvnSslServerTrustEventArgs e)
{
    e.AcceptedFailures = e.Failures;
    e.Save = true;
}
```

Comment: Just so that it's been mentioned: Do not call 'client.authentication.clear()' after subscribing to the event, or otherwise it will not fire.

Comment: @SanBen Thank you, thank you, thank you! I was hung up on that point for hours today.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the SVN server was running VisualSVN Server 3.5.3 with Integrated Windows Authentication enabled. Using SharpSvn 1.9004.3879.127, the SVN client tried to use Windows authentication even when I configured it with a username and password:

```cs
client = new SvnClient();
client.Authentication.Clear(); //Prevents saving/loading config to/from disk
client.Authentication.DefaultCredentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

This resulted in the following error when the application code was run by a Windows user that didn't have access to the repository:

> SvnRepositoryIOException: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://mysvnserver/svn/reponame'

I fixed this by [only allowing `basic` and `digest` authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19801516/238753):

```cs
client = new SvnClient();
client.Configuration.SetOption("servers", "global", "http-auth-types", "basic;digest");
client.Authentication.Clear(); // Prevents saving/loading config to/from disk
client.Authentication.DefaultCredentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```