# Command line SVN ignores provided credentials and uses windows user instead

Tags: svn, command-line, import, version-control, commit

I'm trying to import some files into my SVN via Command line like this:

```
 svn import -m "message" "mypath" "https://mysvn" --username "user" --password "password"
```

The issue I'm facing is that the provided credentials are completely ignored and instead my windows user is taken for authentication at the SVN. So the import succeeds but the SVN history mentions my Windows user as Author and not the user I provided via command line.

Is anyone familiar with this issue? Is there a way the get the credentials in the command used for import instead of the windows user?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question itself is kind of meaningless because you haven't specified what kind of server you are using and how it is configured. Ask your sysadmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered in the thread:
[In SVN how do I override automatic Windows domain authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801515/in-svn-how-do-i-override-automatic-windows-domain-authentication)

Thus, in your case, using the command line

```
svn import -m "message" "mypath" "https://mysvn" --username "user" --password "password" --config-option servers:global:http-auth-types=basic;digest
```

should do the job.

Answer (score 2):

I can only guess that your server is using [AD Single Sign-On](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/windows-auth/) and therefore you are getting authenticated under your user account's credentials. Enter another account's credentials to [Windows Credential Manager](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows7/Store-passwords-certificates-and-other-credentials-for-automatic-logon) if you want to use other user account.