# TortoiseSVN: authentication error

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have been getting:

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'xxx'
Error running context: An error occurred during authentication
```

I've tried clearing cache, authentication data. Tried svn info --username xxx --password xxx --no-auth-cache from cmd. Tried deleting roaming/subversion, roaming/TortoiseSvn, local/TortoiseSVN, deleteing TortoiseSVN in registry and reinstalling tortoiseSVN. But still the same error. Though i can access the repo from be browser. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

If it's caused by using Microsoft Account instead of Local Account to log in your Windows, the solution is in the SO link below. It's just difficult to find it because it doesn't talk exactly about TortoiseSVN, but the Subversion library which is under the hood of TortoiseSVN:

[In SVN how do I override automatic Windows domain authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801515/in-svn-how-do-i-override-automatic-windows-domain-authentication#answer-19801516)

From the answer:

1. In "%AppData%\Subversion\servers" add into [groups] this line:

   yoursvnserver_com = *.yoursvnserver.com
2. In the same file later add this group:

   [yoursvnserver_com]

   http-auth-types=basic;digest

Comment: Step 1 has the wrong path defined for windows. This
`"%AppData%\Subversion\servers"` should be this `"%AppData%\Roaming\Subversion\servers"`.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting this same error trying to log into SVN using windows credentials.  My computer was not part of the domain.  I'm not sure if the fact that my computer was not part of the domain contributes to the problem.

The login screen has a checkbox "Remember my credentials".  If I do not check this box when logging in to SVN, I get the error message "An error occurred during authentication".  If I do check the box "Remember my credentials", the problem goes away forever.

I think in my situation, subversion may refer to those credentials several times during a repo browse or checkout and so not storing the credentials will prevent it from completing.

Several other message boards are recommending that you manually create an entry in the Windows Credential Manager.  Checking the box "Remember my credentials" seems to create this entry automatically.

Comment: Don't forget to check how old a Question is before answering. This didn't have an accepted answer and your answer may help future site users, so otherwise it's good by me.

Comment: Worked for me.  The problem started after I changed my domain password. I cleared the old password from cache, but kept getting the error.  Checking the "remember me" was the solution.  +1

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2020: to me this error was caused by an expired password.**

My Windows domain password was expired, just lock your screen and unlock to get prompted
a password change and after that it was fixed

Answer (score 0):

Contact the sysadmin and administrator of your server. You can't troubleshoot this problem without checking what's going on on the server and how it is configured.

BTW, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I've already done that. He checked server logs, and could not find any record of me, when searching by username / ip address. And said that it's probably some problem with my account or svn client. I doubt it's problem with my account since i can browse svn through browser. And i reinstalled svn client so it shouldn't be it either. Could it be that windows have saved somewhere some old svn credentials and svn client just takes it from there. BTW when i reinstalled TortoiseSVN it still didn't ask me for any credentials.

Comment: @Simas.B does your server use Negotiate for authentication (Integrated Windows Authentication)? Are you in AD domain? Is your computer in domain?

Comment: Yes, me and my computer are in domain. Don't know about Negotiate for authentication part, though.

Comment: @Simas.B first and foremost, I'm pretty sure that server logs contain events relevant to this issue. Double-check the URL that you use to access the repositories **and** check Windows Credential Manager -- there is a chance that some invalid credentials were saved there.

Comment: Admin checked logs couple times, when i was trying to access svn through TortoiseSVN he said he didn't find anything. When i accessed svn through browser he then found records. I'm positive that i'm using good URL's, i've copy, pasted URL from error msg into browser and i've accessed it.I've checked windows credentials manager and theres nothing there. I even tried adding credentials for svn but still, same error.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and was able to fix it.

I somehow managed to switch from a local account to a Microsoft account, which automatically send the (wrong) account authentication to the SVN server.

Once I switch back to a local account, TortoiseSVN works again.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `C:\Users\your_user\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth`, delete all the files.

It'll require you to log in at the SVN again.

Comment: That didn't help. Subversion never asks for credentials to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth" and delete all files. It'll solve your problem, requesting new credentials.

Comment: Hey Paraguas, can you explain more properly why it need to delete all the files? It sounds rather risky the way I read it.

Comment: Steven, before i came to that solution, i had tried everything to authenticate my credentials on SVN with no success. But, speaking more specifically, in the configuration of that directory, you have 4 folders but only one have a file, the folder "svn.simple". You can delete the file with no fear. It was a risky decision but it works properly.