# How can I address the SVN errors E170013 and E120190 when I try to checkout in a WSL2 directory?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, svn, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I can't interact with the SVN server from my Ubuntu in a WSL2 environment. I keep getting the following errors:

```
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://path-to-the-svn-server'
svn: E120190: Error running context: An error occurred during authentication
```

Suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45299260/tortoisesvn-authentication-error) didn't work.
Basic authentication is not an option.

From WSL2, server can be pinged successfully and Internet access is ok.
From Windows, svn is working fine (via TortoiseSVN).

Comment: It's unclear from your questions what SVN server you are using, what SVN versions and what authentication protocols are involved. Is the question about Windows authentication in Active Directory? You need to update your question with all this information.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is about AD and your SVN server is AD-enabled, then you need to join your Linux VM (WSL or whatever) to your AD domain and ensure that Kerberos authentication works with this client VM in your AD domain. AFAIK, Ubuntu has [`sssd`](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-sssd) that should help you join your WSL Linux VM into your domain.