# Ankhsvn Visual Studio subversion plugin, how to configure different credentials

Tags: visual-studio, svn, credentials, ankhsvn

I am trying to add some source control in my project from visual studio. At work, there is already a SVN server configured which some colleagues are already using. My problem is that eventhough I can reach the server from my workstation, I get access denied with my normal user. I got other credentials which are valid (already tested directly in the server via RDP) but I dont know how can I configure the credentials inside the ankhsvn pluggin.

I tried to add the repository with the user at front but it does not work.
https://user@server.here

I also emptied the cache and I get a prompt related to the ssl certificate but not for the user credentials.

do you know how could configure VS or the plugin to use different credentials?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you use [Integrated Windows Authentication](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/windows-auth/) on the server (Negotiate: Kerberos or NTLM)? I mean Active Directory Single Sign-On. If you do, try to add your account's username/password to the Windows Credential Manager. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19813080/761095